# Deleting duplicate records when using text datatype

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a large (~678,000 rows) table storing emails, and I need to delete duplicate records that match the fields of the email: to, from, subject, body, as well as the foreign key record_id.

Normally I would use the following statement to remove duplicates:

```
DELETE
FROM emails
WHERE email_id NOT IN (
SELECT MAX(email_id) FROM emails
GROUP BY record_id, from_add, to_add, subject, body)
```

However, body is datatype `text`, so it cannot be compared/grouped. It gives the following error message on the select query:

```
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.
```

What is the best way to identify duplicates with the `text` datatype? Do I have to convert the column to `varchar` first?

Comment: Can you afford to change the datatype to `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)`?

Comment: That's my last resort/backup plan. I'm hoping there's a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't *have* to `convert` the actual column. Just its usage in the `SELECT` query.

For a one off clean up task I'd probably just go

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY record_id, 
                                                from_add, 
                                                to_add, 
                                                subject, 
                                                CAST(body AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
                                       ORDER BY email_id DESC) RN
         FROM   emails)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  RN > 1
```

Unless dealing with huge amounts of data that might make spending time on a more efficient solution (that doesn't have to sort huge strings) worthwhile.

Or alternatively you could try

```
;WITH T
     AS (SELECT MAX(email_id) AS max_email_id
         FROM   emails
         GROUP  BY record_id,
                   from_add,
                   to_add,
                   subject,
                   CAST(body AS VARCHAR(max)))
DELETE e1
FROM   emails e1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   T
                   WHERE  max_email_id = e1.email_id)
```

This is likely to give you a better plan than `NOT IN` as SQL Server treats `MAX(not_nullable_column)` as being potentially nullable and hence [you end up with a potentially more expensive plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists/11074428#11074428).

[image: Plan]

Comment: Perfect - this is what I was looking for. Thank you! Out of curiosity - you used a `cte` and changed the format of the query rather than adding `CAST(body AS VARCHAR(MAX)` to my original query... why is that?

Comment: @bd33 - Often this is cheaper although maybe not in this case as a hash aggregate on the long strings could well turn out better than sorting them. Check the execution plans for both versions.

Answer (score 3):

Try hashing thusly:

```
select master.sys.fn_repl_hash_binary( Cast( Cast( body as VarChar(max) ) as VarBinary(max) ) )
  from emails
```

If that works you should be able to group by the hash value of the `body` to match messages.

Thanks to [John Huang](http://www.sqlnotes.info/2012/01/16/generate-md5-value-from-big-data/).

Comment: It returns the error:

    `Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
    Cannot find either column "master" or the user-defined function
    or aggregate "master.sys.fn_repl_hash_binary", or the name is ambiguous.`


So I looked in the functions for both the master system database and the database in question and did not find that function. Any advice? What am I missing?

I'm not really a DBA, apologies for the novice question. :)

Comment: @bd33 - My bad.  I tested it on SQL Server 2008, though I thought that I has seen others refer to it being available in 2005.  I just checked my elder 2005 system and it isn't there.  Please have a look at the function defined in the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717977/sql-server-2008-and-hashbytes).  It survived a quick test on my 2005 system.  (Use `'MD5'` for `@Algo`.)